# Automorphisms of a boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Let $A = P(\mathbb{N})$ be the powerset of the natural numbers. We can look at $A$ as the Boolean aglebra - having in mind the obvious operations on elements of $A$.

What I am interested in knowing is if perhaps the following holds:

> If $f:A\mapsto A$ is an automorphism of $A$ then $f(\{x\}) = \{y\}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

In other words, an automorphism of $A$ preserves singletons (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Homomorphisms_and_isomorphisms) for a definition of homomorphism ).

I was not able to find a proof of this fact but neither a counterexample.

Is anyone able to settle this question for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28order_theory%29) of the Boolean algebra $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ are precisely the singletons.

The property of *being an atom* (*atomicity*, if there is such a word) is preserved by isomorphisms. (In particular, by [automorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism)).

---

If you only want homomorphism from $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to itself, then you can take any [ultrafilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) $\mathcal F$ on $\mathbb N$ and put $$\varphi(A)=
  \begin{cases}
    \mathbb N & A\in\mathcal F, \\
    \emptyset & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$

This is a homomorphism, which does not map singletons to singletons.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f(\{x\})$ is not a singleton, then there are two distinct $u,v\in f(\{x\})$ therefore $\{u\},\{v\}\subseteq f(\{x\})$. This means that $f^{-1}(\{u\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{v\})\subseteq\{x\}$ and that both are non-empty.

This is a contradiction that this implies $u=v$.